# ARM11/ARMv6 cache flushing on VM mapping changes?

Tags: operating-system, arm, bare-metal, mmu

I'm writing a toy operating system for the Raspberry Pi, which is based around an ARM11/ARMv6. I want to use basic memory mapping features, mainly so I can swap code in and out of a particular virtual address. I'm intending to use the 1MB sections because they look pretty simple and they're big enough that I only need to change one at a time.

However, there are two things I haven't been able to figure out yet --- the ARM ARM is nigh impenetrable...

- when changing a mapping by updating a TLB table entry, do I need to invalidate that region of virtual address space? Some of the diagrams I've seen indicate that the caches are attached to *physical* memory, but suggests no, but the caching behaviour is controlled by flags on the TLB table entry, which suggests yes.
- if I have two regions of virtual memory pointing at the same physical location, are they cache coherent? Can I write to one and then assume that data is immediately readable from the other? It'd make life loads easier if it were...

Does anyone know the answers for sure?

Comment: When you update the 1MB section...  You need to flush the old memory from cache to core.  You must flush the TLB to invalidate any physical address associated.  Then you should invalidate the cache entry (so the old data is no good).  You can probably intermix the last two if things are happening atomically.  No, the regions are not cache coherent.  I think this answer is useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345290/what-is-the-improvement-in-arm11-for-cache  If it is VIPT then they are not cache coherent unless you do not allow the memory to be cached (often needed for DMA, etc).

Comment: The 'VI' (virtual index) part means that each address should have a separate cache entry.  The CPU would have to have cache logic to detect if any 'PT' (physical tag) in any location was in conflict.  This seems like a lot of logic.  The opposite (same VI) accessing different PT is more common.  Address 0x1000 (or something like that) is a common program entry point.  Different processes will have different physical memory for their code.  There are probably examples in the ARM TRM or maybe appnotes on their web site.

Comment: So the Pi's ARM11 has a "PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT nonaliasing instruction cache". This suggests that if I can get the data cache into PIPT mode, then the cache is keyed entirely off physical addresses. This means that I *should* be able to map the same physical page to the different virtual pages --- by the time the cache sees the addresses they've been translated, so it shouldn't care that they're coming from different virtual addresses. Therefore data accesses should be coherent and I shouldn't need to invalidate the data cache, surely?

Comment: Yes, if you have PIPT data cache then there is no aliasing (you still have issues with DMA type hardware).  However, every access needs to do a TLB hit and/or a table walk.  If you only have 1MB sections in your system, this is not a worry (in fact, the TLB size may cover the whole of system RAM).  It is more of a worry for 4k type pages or 2 levels as both need to be in the TLB or they are looked up in a table walk.